# How do I make my VBA code more efficient using For each loops for three different ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have this code that finds matches over three ranges and colors accordingly. It is very slow and I need to figure out how to make it faster.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub Search_Find_Match_Click()
    Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, WorkRng3 As Range, _
    Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

    Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Range For List:", xTitleId, "A2:A1254", Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range For Floorscan:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng3 = Application.InputBox("Range For RSVP:", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    For Each Rng1 In WorkRng1
        rng1Value = Rng1.Value * 1
        For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
            If Not IsEmpty(Rng2.Value) And Rng2.Value <> "" Then
                Rng2.Value = Rng2.Value * 1
            End If
            If rng1Value = Rng2.Value Then
                Rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(125, 244, 66)
            End If
            For Each Rng3 In WorkRng3
                If Not IsEmpty(Rng3.Value) And Rng3.Value <> "" Then
                    rng3Value = Rng3.Value * 1
                End If
                If rng3Value = Rng2.Value Then
                    Rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(247, 113, 113)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Actual results are just what I want, but it is just so slow and I need help finding a more efficient way to do it

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly what this is supposed to do - it's finding common values among 3 ranges? Note - I don't see the point in multiplying the values by 1.  If you took that out, you'd cut your traffic to the worksheet by a 3 orders of magnitude.

Comment: If you have working code that you're looking to improve, your question should be asked on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: So basically the values saved one of the files are stored as text. I am multiplying the values by 1 to make them numbers so it matches. And thank you for letting me know the correct place to post this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you'r checking against matches of `WorkRng2` range values in `WorkRng1` and `WorkRng3`, you could loop through `WorkRng2` cells only

and use `Find()` method of `Range` object to locate any possible match:

```
Dim WorkRng1 As Range, WorkRng2 As Range, WorkRng3 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim xTitleId As String

xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

Set WorkRng1 = Application.InputBox("Range For List:", xTitleId, "A2:A1254", Type:=8)
Set WorkRng2 = Application.InputBox("Range For Floorscan:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set WorkRng3 = Application.InputBox("Range For RSVP:", xTitleId, Type:=8)


For Each Rng2 In WorkRng2
    If Not WorkRng1.Find(what:=Rng2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(125, 244, 66)
    If Not WorkRng3.Find(what:=Rng2.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then Rng2.EntireRow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(247, 113, 113)
Next
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you. This works wonderfully. I couldn't seem to figure out how to do this, it kept giving me an error when i tried to consolidate the for loop. probably because I am not experienced at all with VBA. I did not know about find or the Is Nothing part. Thank you. I works the same and is light speed now. :) Thanks DisplayName.

Comment: Yeah I literally just saw that check mark there. It has been checked.